# How do I customise the ajax call when using form_tag's 'remote' in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Since ujs is assigning the event handler by simply including the jquery ujs source, how do I override any of the $.ajax settings for the specific call?

So many examples use the global methods. Is this just the preferred method?

(I asked an earlier question where I thought all the customisation was available through the data-* attributes.)

Comment: Could you be more specific? Better to use a case or example to show what kind of overriding you want.

Comment: Well I'd like to add a progress handler to the xhr, and I'd like to assign a local 'success' handler -- instead of using the $(document).ajaxSuccess.

Comment: Got your points. I have similar case before. I want to show loading icon for a specific div but found it will be fired if other parts of the page has ajax success. The case is not critical so I gave up and end with a global loading icon :(

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to a specific element's AJAX success by:

```
$element.bind("ajax:success", function(xhr, data, status){
  doSomeStuff();
});
```

Comment: Why might I only be getting the 'ajax:success' event fired on the form? (I'm not getting the global 'ajax:success' broadcast on each DOM element.)

Comment: Just to check, are you saying that you are getting the 'ajax:success' event fired on the form? If so then I can only imagine that UJS is preventing the event from bubbling, which seems unlikely. And if that isn't happening then I'm stumped!

Comment: I am getting the 'ajax:success' fired on the form that is making the ajax call (via :remote). I am not getting the 'ajax:success' event firing on any other element. Here's something strange... I tried binding to all 'div's, to try and trace this, and I got *one* "ajax:success" to fire. I have more than one 'div' in my test page. Thoughts?